# How to install ReactJS in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webstorm

I am trying to install ReactJS in WebStorm IDE, but can't quite figure out how to do so correctly. Is it an external library? Do I just insert a new JavaScript file?

I have node.js installed on my PC and I see the node modules under my current project. Just trying to figure out where I went wrong. None of the YouTube or ReacJS documentation has helped at all.

Also below is a screenshot of what my project looks like. If you click it you can see that I have the node modules installed.

[image: NodeJS Modules]

Comment: Use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Then open the project folder in Webstorm. Or see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html

Comment: In the terminal in webstorm? or a command line prompt?

Comment: Doesn't matter, both should work. Please refer to the 2nd link I gave you, everything is explained there.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!! Will do!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `create-react-app`. You can run this from the command or from inside WebStorm. To do it in WebStorm, go to File | New | Module... in the main menu. Then select Static Web in the left hand pane and React App on the right. Now provide a Module name, Content root, and Module file location. If npm and create-react-app are installed correctly on your system, the rest of the fields should be filled in. Click Finish and WebStorm will run `create-react-app`.